# OnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

Hello can anybody help me to handle this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview.MainActivity$AddServerFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:141)
```

141 is at `btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

**Fragment: AddServerFragement**

```
public class AddServerFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }

    public AddServerFragment(){
    }

    Button btn_back, btn_add;
    EditText server_ip, server_name;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_ip, container, false);

        server_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);
        server_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_server_name);

        btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String new_server_ip = null, new_server_name = null;

                ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> server_ip_list = new ArrayList<String>();

                new_server_ip = server_ip.getText().toString();
                server_ip_list.add(new_server_ip);

                new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` on the `view` you inflated: `btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
    btn_back= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
```

with

```
    btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
```

Do the same for **all the other layout elements** you wanna initiate.

The reason is: since you inflating a layout file in your Fragment, you have to refer all UI elements to THAT file, that you called "view" here:

```
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_ip, container, false);
```

So the istruction "findViewById" has to be refered to that View view.

Comment: Thank you, thats it, so I must replace `server_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);` with `server_ip = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);` too, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the view inside the view you inflated:

```
btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
```